# Handle multiple spawned processes in Expect script

Tags: expect

Here is my use case for expect script ( one of few i have)

I want to run multiple `sed` command over ssh. Its like pre-build environment setup.
I want to run something like this :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1

spawn -noecho bash -c "ssh -t user@host 'sed -i <some_stuff1> <file1>'"
spawn -noecho bash -c "ssh -t user@host 'sed -i <some_stuff2> <file2>'"
spawn -noecho bash -c "ssh -t user@host 'sed -i <some_stuff3> <file3>'"

expect {
  -re ".*sword.*" {
     exp_send "$env(PASS_WORD)\n"
     exp_continue
  }
}
```

But only last `sed` command will execute. 1st and 2nd will be skipped.

What could be the hidden gem i am missing?

Here is what i looked at so far but not helpful

- [Handle multiple statement in expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658618/handle-multiple-statement-in-expect-script)
- [Expect script: How to handle two processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162069/expect-script-how-to-handle-two-processes)
- [Handling multiple process simuntaneously - safari online book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch11.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need *multiple* (means *parallel*) `spawn` here.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60

set cmds [list "ssh host1 ..." "ssh host2 ..." "ssh host3 ..."]

foreach cmd $cmds {
    spawn -noecho bash -c $cmd
    expect {
        -nocase "password" {
            exp_send "$env(PASS_WORD)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        eof { wait } ; # at this time the last spawn'ed process has exited
    }
}
```

Comment: I do need to run multiple (concurrently) and interact with both of them.  Is there a way to do that?  Some searching used exp_background but that command was not found when I tried it.

Comment: please ask a new question. its not easy to answer in comments.